Passing secrets to reusable worflow
I'm facing a secrets configuration issue with my workflows. I have a caller workflow and a called workflow, where I've set a secret named OPEN_AI_KEY. However, the called workflow fails, indicating that OPEN_AI_KEY is not set. Should I reference the secret from the caller workflow, or is there something else I might be overlooking?
I recently attempted to call a reusable workflow from the caller workflow, both of which reside in the same organization but different repositories. My intention was to invoke the reusable workflow within the caller repository, which contains steps for running Codium PR-Agent upon creating a pull request. Although I've set organization-level secrets in the reusable workflow, the logs indicate an error stating that OPENAI_KEY is not set, despite it being configured.

I think you forgot to inherit the secrets:
jobs:
  example:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable.yml
    secrets: inherit

The reason it's disabled by default, is because a workflow can use, or be used by some third-party workflows, and thus it would be undesirable to make secrets automatically visible for some suspicious external workflows.
For further restricting access to your secrets, you can also pass them one by one as follows:
jobs:
  example:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/reusable.yml
    secrets:
      OPEN_AI_KEY: ${{ secrets.OPEN_AI_KEY }}

